# Is it possible to migrate Oracle SOA BPEL instances from one environment to another with history

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to migrate Oracle SOA BPEL instances from one environment to another with history?

For instance, I want to move from BPEL instances deployed to defined partition on Oracle SOA to another environment. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You do this by having the SOA Infra schema shared between 2 domains. This will let you see the same instances between 2 domain environments.

Comment: Hmm, it is not my case. I asked about migration process from one Domain to Another, not all composite instances, but selected one.

Comment: Composite instances are persisted in SOAINFRA schema. So how many SOAINFRA schema exist for these 2 domains? If it is only one SOAINFRA, the instance will be available on both domains. If it is more than one SOAINFRA, you can look at WFTASK table and its related objects in schema to manually export and import the data to another schema. Before you do that, you might want to rethink the purpose of exporting some instances from one domain(SOAINFRA - A) and import into another domain (SOAINFRA - B).[Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/admin.1111/e10226/soacompapp_mang.htm#CEGIBBHG)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Does SOAINFRA schema description exist?